# How to convert a qubit hamiltonian to QUBO and vice versa?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, annealing, vqe

This is my hamiltonian. Solving this by hand, Numpy Python package and VQE algorithm gives the minimum energy eigenvalue -2. If we want to find the minimum energy of this hamiltonian with Quantum annealer we need to transform this into QUBO. This is a 2 qubit hamiltonian, 4x4 hermitian matrix.

\begin{equation}
H = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 &  1 & 0 \\
0 &  1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  0 &  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
E_{min} = -2
\end{equation}

- What will be the QUBO for this hamiltonian?
- What will be the shape of the QUBO matrix? Is it 4X4 or 2X2?
- How to convert hamiltonian to QUBO? Please elaborate the mathematical steps.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say qubit hamiltonian, that means a hermitian operator expressed as a linear sum of products of Pauli operators right? Cause, normally, QUBOs are obtained only in the case where the Pauli operators are $\sigma^z$ and $\sigma^z \sigma^z$.